# Wicked pdf not rendering footer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wicked-pdf

I'm working on a project that uses wicked_pdf, I have a footer partial which I reference in the pdf generation with:

```
format.pdf do
  render :pdf => "document",
    :footer => {
      :html => {
        :template => "/document/_footer"
      }
  }
end
```

When I run this the the footer isn't displayed on the pdf, but if I have byebugs in the template I can see that the footer is being processed, but not being applied to my document. Any help sorting this out would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the margin:

```
format.pdf do
  render pdf: 'document',
         footer: { html: { template:"/document/_footer" },
         margin: { top: 10, left: 20, bottom: 15, right: 20 }
end
```